# selecting highest value in a table

Tags: awk, sed

A file having 3 columns with tab separated. I want to select the highest value from  column 3rd (among the same name of column 1st) and print as the 4th column.

input file

```
A       l       10
A       l       2
A       m       6
B       l       12
B       m       13
B       n       7
C       l       9
C       l       8
C       n       19
```

Output file

```
A       l       10      10
A       l       2       10
A       m       6       10
B       l       12      13
B       m       13      13
B       n       7       13
C       l       9       19
C       l       8       19
C       n       19      19
```

Could you please suggest awk,or sed command. Thanks

Comment: Are these numbers always positive?

Comment: Excellent, insightful, solution-impacting question from @Ashkan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {arr[$1]=arr[$1]>$3?arr[$1]:$3;next} {print $0,arr[$1]}' OFS="\t" file{,}
A       l       10      10
A       l       2       10
A       m       6       10
B       l       12      13
B       m       13      13
B       n       7       13
C       l       9       19
C       l       8       19
C       n       19      19
```

This passes two times over the `file`. First time to find highest, next to print.
The `file{,}` make the filename double.  You can also use `file file` instead.